# Team Services - Creating work items through API takes longer than retrieving current work items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-devops

I have an ASP .NET MVC app that allows users to create work items by calling to the API. After creating the work item, I am redirecting to a page that displays current work items (another API call). However, the API request to retrieve work items is processing faster than creating the work item, resulting in the display not showing the work item that was just created. I am currently using thread.sleep for testing, but would like guidance on a proper way to handle this.

This is my controller action handling the submit button after creating a work item

```
WICreator addNewWI = new WICreator();
addNewWI.CreateWorkItem(model.SystemTitle, model.SystemDescription);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
return RedirectToAction("WorkItems", "Home");
```

And here is the call to the API to create a work item

```
public void CreateWorkItem(string title, string description)
    {
      string personalAccessToken = "xxx"
      string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "xxx", personalAccessToken)));
      string project = "xx"
      string path = "xx"

        Object[] patchDocument = new Object[3];
        patchDocument[0] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Title", value = title };
        patchDocument[1] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.AreaPath", value = path };
        patchDocument[2] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Description", value = description };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);

            var patchValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "https://xx.xx.com/xx/_apis/wit/workitems/xxxapi-version=1.0") { Content = patchValue };
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the code for WICreator

Comment: @ScottChamberlain updated with the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of creating work item contains the necessary information of new work item, so a simple workflow to deal with this issue is:

1. Save the response of creating work item to an object and send to action by using [TempData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx)
2. Retrieve work items from server
3. Check TempData is null or not
4. Check whether there is the same work item ID in the result of step 2 if TeamData has value
5. If not the same data in the result of step 2, add TempData’s data to model that pass to view

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!